# OpenCV motion detection and tracking

Tags: python, opencv, video

I've been tinkering with Python and OpenCV for a while now, and thought I'd start an actual project. This is my first time making something that I'd actually consider using, and my first time posting to Code Review SE. I'm curious to know your thoughts and opinions on the cleanliness of my code, the efficiency of the program, and the project in general!

The basic function of the program is to find and track objects. I am thinking of hooking this up to a webcam and stepper motor and testing this as a tracking security camera. The program first creates a background image, and then loops until it finds a difference between what it sees currently, and the background image. The difference of these images is taken, then made into its own frame (frame_delta). If this delta is large enough, it is treated as a contour. If there are multiple contours, the largest one is chosen. Once a contour is found, an MIL tracker is created, and set to the size of the contour. This process is repeated every 30 frames to prevent the object from being lost due to tracker inaccuracy. Here's the code!:

```
# OpenCV for tracking/display
import cv2
import time

# When program is started
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Are we finding motion or tracking
    status = 'motion'
    # How long have we been tracking
    idle_time = 0

    # Background for motion detection
    back = None
    # An MIL tracker for when we find motion
    tracker = cv2.TrackerMIL_create()

    # Webcam footage (or video)
    video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    # LOOP
    while True:
        # Check first frame
        ok, frame = video.read()

        # Grayscale footage
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        # Blur footage to prevent artifacts
        gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(21,21),0)

        # Check for background
        if back is None:
            # Set background to current frame
            back = gray

        if status == 'motion':
            # Difference between current frame and background
            frame_delta = cv2.absdiff(back,gray)
            # Create a threshold to exclude minute movements
            thresh = cv2.threshold(frame_delta,25,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

            #Dialate threshold to further reduce error
            thresh = cv2.dilate(thresh,None,iterations=2)
            # Check for contours in our threshold
            _,cnts,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)


            # Check each contour
            if len(cnts) != 0:
                # If the contour is big enough

                # Set largest contour to first contour
                largest = 0

                # For each contour
                for i in range(len(cnts)):
                    # If this contour is larger than the largest
                    if i != 0 & int(cv2.contourArea(cnts[i])) > int(cv2.contourArea(cnts[largest])):
                        # This contour is the largest
                        largest = i

                if cv2.contourArea(cnts[largest]) > 1000:
                    # Create a bounding box for our contour
                    (x,y,w,h) = cv2.boundingRect(cnts[0])
                    # Convert from float to int, and scale up our boudning box
                    (x,y,w,h) = (int(x),int(y),int(w),int(h))
                    # Initialize tracker
                    bbox = (x,y,w,h)
                    ok = tracker.init(frame, bbox)
                    # Switch from finding motion to tracking
                    status = 'tracking'


        # If we are tracking
        if status == 'tracking':
            # Update our tracker
            ok, bbox = tracker.update(frame)
            # Create a visible rectangle for our viewing pleasure
            if ok:
                p1 = (int(bbox[0]), int(bbox[1]))
                p2 = (int(bbox[0] + bbox[2]), int(bbox[1] + bbox[3]))
                cv2.rectangle(frame,p1,p2,(0,0,255),10)


        # Show our webcam
        cv2.imshow("Camera",frame)


        # If we have been tracking for more than a few seconds
        if idle_time >= 30:
            # Reset to motion
            status = 'motion'
            # Reset timer
            idle_time = 0

            # Reset background, frame, and tracker
            back = None
            tracker = None
            ok = None

            # Recreate tracker
            tracker = cv2.TrackerMIL_create()


        # Incriment timer
        idle_time += 1

        # Check if we've quit
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord("q") or cv2.getWindowProperty('Camera',0) == -1:
            break

#QUIT
video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1):

seems cool to me, but i'm not a great expert.

one thing i would improve is the `# for each contour` using built-in python `max()` function as in:

```
largest = max(map(lambda x: int(cv2.contourArea(x)), cnts))
```